# Não consigo executar uma aplicação em modo debug x86

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilação

Estou com problemas em minha aplicação, pois quando compilo em debug anycpu, ela roda perfeitamente, mas quando compilo em debug x86 ela apresenta o seguinte erro:

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Foi feita uma tentativa de se
>   carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT:
>   0x8007000B).

Logo após consegui compilar em debug x86 e exportei a aplicação para instalá-la em outra máquina para testar e o erro continuou, mas apareceu um relatório com mais informações do erro:

> ```
> See the end of this message for details on invoking 
> just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>    at EZClientCSharp.EZInterface.TestConnection()
>    at EZClientCSharp.Form1.ReadPumpsStatus()
>    at EZClientCSharp.Form1.timerAppLoop_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
> mscorlib
>     Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> EZClientCSharp
>     Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Eztech-Teste/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/R8Y36OTB.RYR/K54ZCLR3.HV2/ezcl..tion_7801d6183abab3fc_0001.0000_cf0a8c3c24228d3d/EZClientCSharp.exe
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Windows.Forms
>     Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System
>     Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Drawing
>     Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
> ----------------------------------------
>
> ************** JIT Debugging **************
> To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
> application or computer (machine.config) must have the
> jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
> The application must also be compiled with debugging
> enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
> </configuration>
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
> will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
> rather than be handled by this dialog box.
> ```

Comment: Se rodar sem debugar (Ctrl + F5) funciona?

Comment: Não. Mesmo erro.

Comment: inclui a configuração do JIT debug no app.config para tentar ver melhor qual rotina/funcão/código está causando o erro: `<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>`

Comment: Eu passei por este problema e no MEU caso era versão de DLL, ela tem que ser compatível com o que está rodando, sendo 32Bits ou 64Bits.

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal. Consegui resolver com a dica do LP. Gonçalves. Era a versão da dll. Abraços.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível resolver este problema carregando a `dll` correta para o ambiente, ela tem que ser compatível com o que está rodando, sendo 32Bits ou 64Bits.